# I have a LINQ statement that is partially query and partially method. How can I do this using one or the other?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Here is my query as it stands now:

```
Goals = await (from p in _context.FixtureActivityTb 
               where p.ActivityType.Trim() == "G" 
               group p by p.PlayerId into x 
               join j in _context.PlayerTb on x.Key equals j.PlayerId 
               select new Stats 
               { 
                   Name = j.GivenName, 
                   pID = j.PlayerId, 
                   TeamId = j.TeamId, 
                   Count = x.Count() 
               })
   .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count)
   .ThenBy(s => s.Name)
   .Take(10)
   .ToListAsync();
```

As you can see this is a mix of method and query. I should be able to do a join, where, and add the data to a custom class all in Method, however so far I have not been able to put it all together. Any guidance will be appreciated.

I will include these other items, however, I think they are beside the point.

Variable Declaration:

```
public IList<Stats> Goals { get; set; }
```

Class:

```
public class Stats
{
    public Guid pID { get; set; }
    public string TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It costs some money, but you can get a ReSharper. One of its features is an ability to convert your code into LINQ expressions with extensions methods.

Comment: I should have noted that I am using .Net core 3.0 None of these now work, and not even the statement that I have above works now. The reason for this is the following: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes?toc=/dotnet/core/compatibility/toc.json&bc=/dotnet/breadcrumb/toc.json#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client) Anoyingly, because of the ToList, I should be good to go, however it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question (and the lack of coffee isn't affecting me), to get this all to a *Linq chain method*, it should be as simple as

```
Goals = await _context.FixtureActivityTb.Where(p => p.ActivityType.Trim() == "G")
                      .GroupBy(p => p.PlayerId)
                      .Join(_context.PlayerTb, x => x.Key, j => j.PlayerId, (x, j)
                          => new Stats
                             {
                                Name = j.GivenName,
                                pID = j.PlayerId,
                                TeamId = j.TeamId,
                                Count = x.Count()
                             })
                      .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count)
                      .ThenBy(s => s.Name)
                      .Take(10)
                      .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I will try this soon. Results to come. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite acceptable to mix the two, especially where you have a base query, and a paging part, as here.  You can even compose the queries over multiple statements, eg:

```
var q = from p in _context.FixtureActivityTb 
        where p.ActivityType.Trim() == "G" 
        group p by p.PlayerId into x 
        join j in _context.PlayerTb on x.Key equals j.PlayerId 
        select new Stats 
        { 
            Name = j.GivenName, 
            pID = j.PlayerId, 
            TeamId = j.TeamId, 
            Count = x.Count() 
        };

Goals = await q.OrderByDescending(s => s.Count)
               .ThenBy(s => s.Name)
               .Take(10)
               .ToListAsync();
```